# CSS grey box with white text

Tags: css

New to HTML and I am working on a project for class. Here is what I did:

```
<font style="background-color: grey; color: white; display: block">Black and white copies $.10 per page letter/legal size</font>

 Color copies $.99 per page letter/legal size<br>

<font style="background-color: grey; color: white; display: block">Transparencies $1.98 per page full color</font>

Transparencies $.61 per page black and white<br>
```

It tests fine in the browser, but when I go to validate the file, WC3 Validator gives me an error message saying : *"Line 33 and 37, Column 71: The font element is obsolete. Use CSS instead."*

How can I write that grey box/reverse text into my CSS page?

Thank you for any help!
Greg

Comment: Use an element that is not obsolete. The same markup would work fine if you replace `font` with `span`, for example.

Comment: ACJ -Validates now, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

use block tag to replace the font tag - use `<div>` and remove `display:block` because it becomes usless